# JInternalFrame Cursor Not changing

Tags: java, linux, swing, cursor, jinternalframe

I have a JDesktopPane with cursor set to WAIT. Later I am adding an JInternalFrame to the desktop pane and setting it visible. But the cursor doesn't seem to change to WAIT. Why Parent's cursor is not applied to the child?

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;

import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws PropertyVetoException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    JDesktopPane pane = new JDesktopPane();
    pane.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
    frame.getContentPane().add(pane);

    frame.setVisible(true);

    JInternalFrame iFrame = new JInternalFrame("MyFrame");
    iFrame.setMaximizable(true);
    iFrame.setResizable(true);
    iFrame.setSize(200, 200);
    pane.add(iFrame);
    iFrame.setVisible(true);
    iFrame.moveToFront();
    iFrame.setSelected(true);
}

}
```

Comment: works for me correctly in Win8/XP, Java7/6

Comment: I am using a linux system with Metal Look and Feel

Comment: have to wait, here are a few very good answerers with ***nix

Comment: Likewise it works for me on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: When I print the cursor of JInternalFrame it is Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR, but displays Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR.